# Joining/combining movestacks in R?

Tags: r

I'm trying to combine ten separate move stacks of different species and study areas into one single move stack using the move package. I can't mind any documentation on how to do this without converting them to data frames. Does anyone know how to do this while keeping the object as a movestack?

I've even tried converting them and then trying to combine the data frames; however, it often returns an error or creates a value with the data of the move stacks being stored separately.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: From the package's website https://bartk.gitlab.io/move/articles/move.html#handling-multiple-animals:  "A MoveStack can also be created from a list of multiple Move or MoveStack objects with the function moveStack().  In this case all objects have to be in the same projection, and their timestamps have to be in the same time zone. Most functions of the Move package are capable of working with MoveStacks."